# How to get name of logged user (Flask, SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to authomaticaly put name to authors blogged from loged in session.
So far I can log user but when he is already logged I cant find way to work with his name on site.

So I am trying to create some way, which will store username after he is logged in memory and flask will then use this username for blog posts and comments or editing profile. Thank you

```
Base = declarative_base()
class User(Base):

     __tablename__ = "users"

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     username = Column(String(64))
     password = Column(String(120))
     email = Column(String(64))

     def __init__(self, username, password, email):

         self.username = username
         self.password = password
         self.email = email



Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Base2 = declarative_base()
class Blogpost(Base2):

    __tablename__ = 'blogpost'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(50))
    subtitle = Column(String(50))
    author = Column(String(20))
    date_posted = Column(DateTime)
    content = Column(Text)

    def __init__(self, title, subtitle, author, date_posted, content):

         self.title = title
         self.subtitle = subtitle
         self.author = author
         self.date_posted = date_posted
         self.content = content

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():

     POST_USERNAME = str(request.form['username'])
     POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])

def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
    password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
    return password == hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + user_password.encode()).hexdigest()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = Session()
user = s.query(User).filter_by(username=POST_USERNAME).first()
if check_password(user.password, POST_PASSWORD) == True:
    session['logged_in'] = True
    user_name = POST_USERNAME
else:
    flash('wrong password!')
return index()

@app.route('/add')
def add():
     return render_template('add.html')

@app.route('/addpost', methods=['POST'])
def addpost():
     title = request.form['title']
     subtitle = request.form['subtitle']
     content = request.form['content']

     Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
     session = Session()
     post = Blogpost(title=title, subtitle=subtitle, author=user_name,   content=content, date_posted=datetime.now())

     session.add(post)
     session.commit()
```

Comment: Where do `sessionmaker` and `engine` come from? To do what you're trying to do, one should usually use `flask.session`, but if you ask me, these look like SQLAlchemy objects.

Comment: Why don't you use Flask's extensions to deal with User session management, like Flask-Login?

Comment: I think `def check_password()` has malformed indent - please fix it.

Comment: The line with `return index()`  -  shouldn't it be inside some route function?

Comment: Thank you all, flask-login was much better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encourage you to use an extension like flask-login for user management or flask-security for extended features, meanwhile, you can store the user in flask sessions.

first import session (i will call it login_session to differentiate it with your sql-alchemy session)

```
from flask import session as login_session
```

Then once a user logs in you can store the user details like this

```
login_session['username'] = user.username #user here being the user object you have queried
```

And to access the user name from session

```
username  = login_session['username']
```

and once a user logs out, you delete the user details from session like this

```
del login_session['username']
```

But as others have mentioned in the comments, for a serious web app, you will want to consider using one of the flask extensions for user management

Comment: Thank you, flask-login was indeed much better solution to this problem.